Decoupling capacitor for drone power supply
I am working on a mini drone project. For the power supply, I am using a 1S LiPo (3.7 V) battery with a Schottky diode for protection. I plan to use a decoupling capacitor to handle rapid voltage changes.
What value of capacitor should i use? (C1 on schematic)
Full schematic:


What does the ESP32 datasheet say?

i can't find anything about recommended value for the capacitor, but the board already has a 22uF/10V decoupling capacitor for AMS1117-3.3 input

or can you help me about keywords that i have to find in datasheet?

Try to find a better solution which replaces D6 and its voltage drop. There are other ways to implement a reverse battery protection, e.g. P-FET. There is nearly no voltage headroom for the LDO in the ESP module.

Which capacitor you mean? C1? Or some other capacitor?

@Jens Okay, i will take a note

@Justme Yeah C1

The capacitor does not "handle rapid voltage changes". What it does do is handle rapid current changes and prevent them from becoming voltage changes. In order to pick a value, you need to analyze your circuit and determine what causes the biggest current transients. The ESP32 is one source (when transmitting), but you also have the four motors, which you are presumably PWMing for speed control.
You also need to have some idea of how much of a voltage transient your system can tolerate, and also know something about the effective source impedance of your battery and diode. Together, these will give you some constraints on the value of the capacitor. The ESR/ESL of the capacitor itself will also play a role, and multiple capacitors may be required to give you the results you require over the full range of frequencies involved.
